# Solving differential equation with ODEINT in python

Tags: python, numpy, ode

I have a coupled system of differential equations that I've already solved with Euler in Excel. Now I want to make it more precise with an ODE-solver in python.
However, there must be a mistake in my code because the curves look different than in Excel. I don't expect the curves to reach 1 and 0 in the end.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define reactor
def reactor(x,z):
    n_a = x[0]
    n_b = x[1]
    n_c = x[2]

    dn_adz = A * (-1) * B * (n_a/(n_a + n_b + n_c)) / (1 + C * (n_c/(n_a + n_b + n_c)))
    dn_bdz = A * (1) * B * (n_a/(n_a + n_b + n_c)) / (1 + C * (n_c/(n_a + n_b + n_c)))
    dn_cdz = A * (1) * B * (n_a/(n_a + n_b + n_c)) / (1 + C * (n_c/(n_a + n_b + n_c)))
    dxdz = [dn_adz,dn_bdz,dn_cdz]
    return dxdz

# initial conditions
n_a0 = 0.5775
n_b0 = 0.0
n_c0 = 0.0
x0 = [n_a0, n_b0, n_c0]

# parameters
A = 0.12
B = 3.1e-9
C = 4.02e15

# number of steps
n = 100

# z step interval (m)
z = np.linspace(0,0.0274,n)

# solve ODEs
x = odeint(reactor,x0,z)


# Plot the results
plt.plot(z,x[:,0],'b-')
plt.plot(z,x[:,1],'r--')
plt.plot(z,x[:,2],'k:')
plt.show()
```

Is is a problem with the initial condition that stays constant and does not change from step to step?
Should it be like in Excel with Euler, where the next step uses the conditions/values of the precious step?

Comment: Your `dn_bdz` and `dn_cdz` are identical, which seems unlikely to be what you want (especially with `n_b0==n_c0`).

Comment: dn_bdz and dn_cdz are identical. Two compounds that are generated from dn_adz. However, you are right, that n_b0 is a little different to n_c0. nb_c0 = 1.5e-5, so almost 0.

Comment: Could you explain a little how you determine that this result is more wrong than the Euler result? Also you might want to use `z = np.linspace(0,0.0274,n+1)` to get the result for `n` steps, as both end points are included in the count.

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of the right sides you get constant combinations of the state variables, `n_a+n_b=n_a0+n_b0` and `n_a+n_c=n_a0+n_c0`. This means that the dynamic reduces to the one-dimensional dynamic of `n_a`.

By the first equation, the derivative of `n_a` is negative for positive `n_a`, so that the solution is falling towards `n_a=0`. By the constants of the dynamics, `n_b` converges to `n_a0+n_b0` and `n_c` converges to `n_a0+n_c0`.

It is unclear how you get convergence towards `1` in some components, as that is not supported by the initial conditions. Apart from that, the described `odeint` result fits this qualitative behavior.

Comment: There is a reaction behind that model. The reaction is A --> B + C. So A is consumed to form B and C. n_a has always to be positiv and the derivative is negative because it is consumed. I've the solution in Excel and for this example I expect n_a falling to around 0.288 and B and C increasing to around 0.288. I got the same results with Euler and Runge-Kutta in Excel, that's why I think there is a mistake here in my first python code. The convergence towards 1 was a mistake. Just normalizes, it's going to 1. However in reality B and C converge to 0.5775.

Comment: Do you also have some inlet for A and some outlet for the mix or extraction of B and C? Else I do not understand why A should not completely be consumed. What I am really asking is, what is the theory behind the fractions on the right side?

Comment: Gosh, I found the mistake. The theory behind the fractions on the right sight are based on a model that was created from experimental results and a parameter estimation. And I haven't used the lastest parameters from my estimation in Excel. Now it works. Such a stupid mistake. However, thank you very much for your help and support. Without you, I would have given up to work with Python. Now I will try to go one step further and do the parameter estimation in Python. I don't know where to start, but I'm sure it will be better than with Excel in the end. Thanks again :)